# How does Git avoid losing work when multiple users push new changes to a remote repo?

Tags: git

I have a bare remote Git repository. Now two users are updating the site. Each of these users clone the Git repository, make changes and push. When they again want to make changes they do a `git pull` to get the latest changes from the remote.

I have some concerns. If user A pulls files from the remote repo and works on them for 1 week, while user B publishes major changes to the remote repo, and then user A again pushes his 1 week old files with some changes, won't there be data inconsistency?

Comment: **tl;dr**: Git will force users to merge their work with new changes on a remote repo before they're allowed to push their own changes, so there will never be "inconsistency" on the remote repo itself, only (temporarily) on local clones.

Comment: Also, Git is not capitalized as "GIT", it's not an abbreviation or an acronym like TFS, SVN, or CVS.

Comment: **Highly recommended reading: [Pro Git - 2.5 Git Basics - Working with Remotes - Pushing to Your Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Pushing-to-Your-Remotes).**

Answer (score 3):

If user A tries to push changes when there are unmerged changes from user B, A will be forced to pull user B's changes and resolve any merge conflicts before pushing out anything else.

When user A tries to push blindly, a message like this would pop up:

```
$ git push
To ssh://userA@example.com/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://userA@example.com/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Here, Git is telling user A to retrieve the changes on the server before pushing out anything else. If no conflicts occur, the output of `git pull` might be something like this:

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From ssh://userA@example.com/repo.git
   27dc3b8..7ef4155  master     -> origin/master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 content.txt | 4 ++++
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
```

In this case, a merge commit is created and user A can push out the changes. If Git can't resolve the changes, though, a message like this will appear:

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From ssh://userA@example.com/repo.git
   38b054e..27dc3b8  master     -> origin/master
Auto-merging content.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in content.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

User A then gets to open the conflicted file (`content.txt`), resolve the problems, and then commits the merge. This isn't necessarily an automatic process; hopefully user A asks user B about any changes that aren't clear or if there are bigger problems.

Comment: @MYNE - Glad to help! If this solved your problem, click the checkmark on the answer to accept it as the solution

Answer (score 2):

In the case of two or more users modifying the same file, one user would run into [merge conflicts](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts).  While these *may* be scary sometimes, they can be dealt with simply.  The *normal* case with merges is that they're merged cleanly, [as a fast-forward merge](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging).

A merge conflict is effectively Git telling you that it cannot cleanly merge the two branches of work together.  The committer must then manually restore the code in such a way that the code would work as intended.

Merge conflicts are common on large teams that share a single commit branch, or large teams with a  large amount of branches (and there are a lot of shared files being edited at the same time).  Ultimately, the team must decide the most ideal approach to resolve conflicts; in general, it's **best** to talk it over with whomever the other committer is.

Answer (score 0):

There's sort of two ways that can go down.

When you're pushing code to a remote repository, Git will try to reconcile your latest changes with the code that's already in the repo. If you're the only user, this is as easy as you'd expect. When you're dealing with multiple users, it still works pretty well most of the time.

Where you're going to get a problem is if two users modify the same bits of a file at the same time. In that case, the push will fail and git will complain about a **merge conflict**, which is when Git says "I'm not smart enough to handle this" and requires a human to go in and do the merge manually before pushing again.

Of course, realize that what I've just said is a massive simplification; the actual process of working with Git is way more complicated than this, and there are lots of different ways to handle conflicting changes. I encourage you to try out some Git tutorials to get a handle on the basics; [GitHub](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) has a pretty good one, and Google will get you to hundreds of others.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. Attempting to push code that hasn't been synchronized with changes in the remote will cause the push to fail completely. Merging will only happen on the local clone when a user pulls (or fetches and merges) the remote changes, but the key point is that it doesn't happen during the push.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My intent had been to address the core of the question without overloading the OP with extra (and to me, unnecessary for the scope of this question) information, hence my suggestion to look for Git tutorials. I've edited my answer to clarify

Comment: The answer is a little better than it was before, but the second paragraph still suggests that Git will attempt to merge during a push.